# How to customize woocommerce password rule , i want write own password rule

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am new to Wordpress, i need to change password rule of woocommerce something like this :

1. Minimum 6 character length.
2. one special character required

Please help .
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This site is about programming and so you gotta show us what you have tried so far to achieve what you want. If you're looking for a tutorial or recommendations this is not the best place to ask. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

See here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/278084/is-it-possible-to-reduce-the-minimum-character-length-for-passwords

> Passwords do not have a minimum character requirement, but there is an minimum strength requirement. The strength is determined by zxcvbn. There are plugins that let you change the strength requirements however, like this one: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-password-strength-settings/